# PlusOneActivity not starting when clicking +1 button in Android app

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-plus, google-play-services

I am integrating a Google +1 button into my Android app. I am using the same fragment with a PlusOne button in my MainActivity and a child activity (SearchActivity). In the SearchActivity the button works fine. Logcat shows:

```
I/ActivityManager(13953): START u0 {act=com.google.android.gms.plus.action.PLUS_ONE cmp=com.google.android.gms/.plus.plusone.PlusOneActivity (has extras)} from pid 3897
I/ActivityManager(13953): Start proc com.google.android.gms.ui for activity com.google.android.gms/.plus.plusone.PlusOneActivity: pid=4061 uid=10010 gids={50010, 3003, 1007, 3002, 3001, 1028, 1015, 1006, 2001, 3006}
I/MultiDex( 4061): load(/data/app/com.google.android.gms-2.apk, forceReload=false)
I/MultiDex( 4061): Need extracted file /data/data/com.google.android.gms/files/secondary-dexes/com.google.android.gms-2.apk.classes2.zip
I/MultiDex( 4061): No extraction needed for /data/data/com.google.android.gms/files/secondary-dexes/com.google.android.gms-2.apk.classes2.zip of size 1547068
D/GCM     ( 2864): GcmService start Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.INITIALIZE flg=0x10 pkg=com.google.android.gms cmp=com.google.android.gms/.gcm.GcmService } com.google.android.gms.INITIALIZE
I/ActivityManager(13953): START u0 {cmp=com.google.android.gms/.plus.activity.AccountSignUpActivity (has extras)} from pid 4061
I/ActivityManager(13953): Displayed com.google.android.gms/.plus.plusone.PlusOneActivity: +2s158ms
I/ActivityManager(13953): Displayed com.google.android.gms/.plus.activity.AccountSignUpActivity: +1s908ms
I/ActivityManager(13953): START u0 {act=com.google.android.gms.common.account.CHOOSE_ACCOUNT cmp=com.google.android.gms/.common.account.AccountPickerActivity (has extras)} from pid 4061
I/ActivityManager(13953): Displayed com.google.android.gms/.common.account.AccountPickerActivity: +1s283ms
```

In my MainActivity the AccountChooser never gets visible. Pushing the +1 button just starts a loader for a little while before returning to the default red button.

Logcat shows:

```
I/ActivityManager(13953): START u0 {act=com.google.android.gms.plus.action.PLUS_ONE cmp=com.google.android.gms/.plus.plusone.PlusOneActivity (has extras)} from pid 4530
W/GmsClientEvents( 4530): registerConnectionCallbacks(): listener bjh@420c6a40 is already registered
I/ActivityManager(13953): Start proc com.google.android.gms.ui for activity com.google.android.gms/.plus.plusone.PlusOneActivity: pid=4727 uid=10010 gids={50010, 3003, 1007, 3002, 3001, 1028, 1015, 1006, 2001, 3006}
I/MultiDex( 4727): load(/data/app/com.google.android.gms-2.apk, forceReload=false)
I/MultiDex( 4727): Need extracted file /data/data/com.google.android.gms/files/secondary-dexes/com.google.android.gms-2.apk.classes2.zip
I/MultiDex( 4727): No extraction needed for /data/data/com.google.android.gms/files/secondary-dexes/com.google.android.gms-2.apk.classes2.zip of size 1547068
D/GCM     ( 2864): GcmService start Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.INITIALIZE flg=0x10 pkg=com.google.android.gms cmp=com.google.android.gms/.gcm.GcmService } com.google.android.gms.INITIALIZE
W/GmsClientEvents( 4530): registerConnectionCallbacks(): listener bjh@42ae18e0 is already registered
```

So it complains about

> registerConnectionCallbacks(): listener bjh@42ae18e0 is already registered

Why could that be and how to prevent it? How could I debug/further investigate this? As written above the +1 button is in the same fragment just a different activity. The activities inherit the same parent classes so there should not be much of a difference.

Thank you for any hints!

Comment: What is in your `onConnected()`

Comment: I do not have an onConnected() method. I am using code generated by Android Studio 0.5.4 which is very close to the SDK samples.

Comment: Have you tried making sure your `GooglePlayServicesClient` is not connected before trying to register a connection callback?

Comment: Frankly spoken no. All I do is call `mPlusOneButton.initialize(URL, 0);` where `mPlusOneButton` is a reference to the `PlusOneButton` instance in my view.

Comment: Hmm, can you post your plusoneactivity.java. Might help me find whats wrong

Comment: It´s too complex to post. Which parts/methods are interesting?

Comment: I dont see the relationship between using plusonebutton.initialise and registerconnectioncallbacks

Comment: Maybe I am pointing you in the wrong direction. Can you see anything else from the logcat extract which could be helpful?

Comment: Well the problem is when you click the button. So maybe you could post your PlusOneButton.OnPlusOneClickListneer

Comment: It must be optional as I did not implement it (and the implementation does work for one of the activities as pointed out above).

Comment: Yeah it is optional, it has a default implementation if you dont override it. Well this has me stumped. I dont know what could be the problem at this point, sorry.

Comment: Thank you @Clay for going through! As a workaround I am checking which Activity I am in and hide the button in the Activity where it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It has to do with the `android:launchMode` configured in the `AndroidManifest.xml`. With launchMode set to `singleInstance` the +1 button does not work.

I successfully tested it with the other launchModes singleTop, singleTask and standard.

Comment: Since you were able to figure it out, would you be so kind as to look at my code please and tell me what I'm doing wrong or missing please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23481918/plusonebutton-in-live-wallpaper-settings-not-working-android